# actions_intent_SIGN_IN not triggered for successful sign in implicit flow account linking

Tags: google-oauth, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I am not able to get the  actions_intent_SIGN_IN triggered once a successful implicit authorization is done.
I do have a welcome Intent and sign.in intent mapped as

```
actionMap.set('input.welcome', DefaultWelcomeIntent);
actionMap.set('sign.in', signIn);
```

and the respective methods are

```
   function DefaultWelcomeIntent() {
    app.askForSignIn();
}

function signIn(app) {
    if (app.getSignInStatus() === app.SignInStatus.OK) {
        let accessToken = app.getUser().accessToken;
        app.ask('Great, thanks for signing in!');
    } else {
        app.ask('I won\'t be able to save your data, but let\'s continue!');
    }
}
```

In the dialog flow, I do have the DefaultWelcome Intent and a follow up intent for the welcome intent. The followup intent has the Events defined as 'actions_intent_SIGN_IN' and action as 'sign.in' . 'Enable Webhook call for this intent' is checked  .

The implicit configuration is as follows in the Account Linking in Actions in Google :

1. Grant Type: Implicit
2. ClientID : Hello123ClientID
3. AuthorizationURL-  https://XXXX.ngrok.io/auth
4. scopes: email

authorization endpoint is

```
app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {

    var clientID = Hello123ClientID
    var redirectURL = 'https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/sampleproject'
    var projectID = 'sampleproject'
    var ACCESS_TOKEN = 'SampleTokenXXXXXX'
    var STATE_STRING;

    if (req.query.client_id) {
        if (req.query.client_id != clientID) {
            res.status(503).send("Incorrect ClientID");
        }
    }
    if (req.query.redirect_uri) {
        if (req.query.redirect_uri != redirectURL) {
            res.status(503).send("Incorrect Re-directURL")
        }
    }
    if (req.query.response_type) {
        if (req.query.response_type != 'token') {
            res.status(503).send("Incorrect Response_type")
        }
    }

    if (req.query.state) {
        STATE_STRING = req.query.state
    }
    var responseoAuthURL ;
    responseoAuthURL = 'https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/' + projectID + '#access_token=' + ACCESS_TOKEN + '&token_type=bearer&state=' + STATE_STRING
    res.redirect(responseoAuthURL)
 });
```

***What is not working***

Once I invoke the welcome intent in mobile , it asks me that the account is not linked and whether I want to link. 
On sending yes, browser is opened and redirects to the auth end point, validates and redirects to the above url and is returned to the app.

I am not getting the event actions_intent_SIGN_IN triggered and method signIn() is not getting called. Not sure what the reason is.

Also fallback intent was removed  and I created a new intent with the action as 'sign.in' and Events as 'actions_intent_SIGN_IN'. and the webhook checked.In this case also the intent method signIn() was not triggered.

***What works :***

I tested the askForPermission , and the same scenario works for me . Once I give permission , the intent with event actions_intent_PERMISSION is getting triggered and respective methods are called.

This sign in workflow  was working for me couple of days before but not I am not able to get it work.Not sure what is happening. Any suggestions would be of great help for me. I used assistant in iphone

Comment: Could you check the History tab in the Training section what Intent is being matched and try to fix it there to the correct intent?

Comment: I checked it but this is what I see here. I don't see the signin intent being called. i.imgur.com/gfhHgPm.png . Is there something wrong ? Also for the askForSignIn if I type in No , the event is getting triggered . Seems the issue is only when we try to link using the implicit oauth endpoint and the response is returned .

Comment: Are you using the AoG Node.js library? if yes is it up to date?

Comment: Yeah I am using the actions on Google 1.8.2 version .

Comment: Yeah I am using the actions on Google 1.8.2 version .As mentioned , when I type "No" for the question "I need to link your my test app account to Google,Is that okay ?" it triggers the event and I am able to get the app.getSignInstatus as "NO" but when I type in "Yes" for the question the auth end point is triggered and the access token is added to the URL which is sent back .But after that in the app scree "Linking Account"is shown and seems the app quits the current context and the assistant images comes up for saying something blinking but nothing happens . Please do help me

Comment: Could you check your Dialogflow history again and share a screenshot but after the second query (after saying "YES" or "NO") (should look like this imgur.com/IfwIUE6)

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issues .but while I was testing to take the screenshot it started working for all temporary projects I had created for this .But the signin method is called twice .Not sure what exactly is happening .anyway it's atleast called twice

Comment: I ran into exactly the same issue. However, taking a screenshot didn't fix it for me ;) Did you ever find out what caused this or how to fix it properly?

Comment: :) Yes, I always tried from the same account in the google assistant and in the same device itself. When I switched the device and tried linking to another account it started working. there after I never had this issue with any of the accounts . Now my app is published and seems its working fine now. https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000298f27f66a?hl=en

Comment: I'm having the same issue, Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Does the device you test this with have screen? I my (very similar) case I received actions_intent_SIGN_IN on mobile phone client, and did not on Google Home device. Skipping actions_intent_SIGN_IN event could be device specific...